# How to post to facebook wall once I've got the access token

Tags: php, facebook

I'm making a facebook app and have got as far as getting the user to allow my apps permissions, which then generates a code. Then using this code to get an access token. So I now have a variable in my PHP script containing the access token. Now how do I use this to post to the users wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to post a message on the wall is through the graph api. You require the  publish_stream permission to post status messages. You can simply do a POST with the desired message and the access token.

See the official facebook documentation for more details: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook changes their API so often, it's best to read their docs, if those are up to date...

Check in IRC #facebook as well.

But basically, you pass that token in to the API call somewhere, somehow and it's in their docs somewhere.

Unless FB has decided you don't need it or ignores it or doesn't want to allow that this week.